# Quantiles in a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, quantiles

Suppose that X is a continuous random variable and $x_{0.25}$, $x_{0.5}$, $x_{0.75}$ are the 25th, 50th and 75th quantiles respectively. How can I write in terms of probabilities the fact that "quantiles are the three cut points that will divide a dataset into four equal-sized groups"?

Comment: This cannot be correct in general, because the *only* datasets that can be divided into four equal-sized groups are those whose count is a multiple of four!

Answer (score 3):

For a continuous random variable with probability density $f(x)$, quantiles are well defined. You can, e.g., use the following definition for the $p$-Quantile $x_p$:
$$p=F(x_p)=\int_{-\infty}^{x_p} f(x)\, dx \quad\Rightarrow\quad x_p=F^{-1}(p)$$
For discrete random variables and empirical samples, there is however no consensus how to define the quantiles in ambiguous (and sometimes even in non-ambiguous) cases. The R-function *quantile* alone offers nine (sic!) different options for the defintion of quantiles. For an overview of common definitions, see

> Hyndman, Rob J., and Yanan Fan. "Sample quantiles in statistical packages." The American Statistician 50.4 (1996): 361-365.

Answer (score 0):

The short version of the answer is that $P(X \le x_{0.25}) = 0.25$ for the lower quartile, Also, in a large sample from the distribution of $X,$ very nearly 25% of observations will be smaller than $x_{0.25}.$ Similar statements hold for the median and upper quartile. The following illustration shows some specific population and sample quantiles.

Suppose you are interested in a population distributed according to a [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution),
$\mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape}=50, \text{rate}=0.5),$ so that the density function of the population is as shown in the figure below. Also, the R function `qgamma` finds quantiles of a gamma distribution; the quantiles are shown by vertical red lines.

```
curve(dgamma(x, 50, 0.5), 0, 200, lwd=2, ylab="PDF",
      main="GAMMA(50,.5)")       
 abline(v=0, col="green2");  abline(h=0, col="green2")
  q = qgamma(c(.25,.5,.75), 50, 0.5)
  abline(v=q, col="red", lwd=2)
  q
[1]  90.13322  99.33413 109.14124
```

[image]

The four areas under the density curve separated by the vertical red lines are equal. (There is sort of an optical illusion here, but the areas ***are*** equal.)

If we simulate a very large sample from this distribution, then its
sample quantiles will nearly match the theoretical quantiles shown above.

[Unless you ask for something different, the `quantile` function also gives the minimum `0%` and maximum `100%`. The theoretical values are $0$ and $\infty,$ but those extreme values are not well estimated even by a huge sample. For very large samples, the differences @cdalitz (+1) notes among software programs are
mostly unimportant. ]

```
x = rgamma(10^6, 50, .5)
quantile(x)
       0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
 42.17696  90.13293  99.31625 109.13695 187.73144 
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Sample of a Million from GAMMA(50,.5)")
 curve(dgamma(x,50,.5), add=T, lwd=2)
 abline(v=samp.q, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]